# JAVA how to cast from superclass to unknown subclass

Tags: java, inheritance, enums, polymorphism

I have an enum like this:

```
enum{
        attribute(instance of subclass, int);
        private superclass
        private int;
}
```

now, when I search into the enum for an attrubute, when i found it i do:

```
superclass variable=value.getSuperclass();
```

So I have a superclass variable which contains a subclass instance
now, I should use subclass method not present in superclass declaration, so I should cast the superclass to unknown subclass.

How can I do it? Is it possible?

Comment: please post real code, as this one that you've posted is some pseudo-code and I can't grasp what you need.

Comment: If I'm understanding this correctly, it sounds like a code smell. Do you have control over the superclass and all of its subclasses? How many of the subclasses need to call non-superclass methods in this situation?

Comment: the enum code is like that, the for is which search into the enum is:  for(Enum enum: Enum){enum.getSuperclass)....}.     half subclasses need the non-superclass method

Answer (score 0):

You can check the type by instanceof keyword,

```
if (myObj instanceof SomeClass) {
   SomeClass someClass = (SomeClass) myObj;
   someClass.someSomeClassMethod();
}
```

But depending on what would you like to achieve you should probably use some pattern. Generally it is wise to construct code in a way that doesn't require to use instanceof, and in general type checking logic.

Comment: Of course, but i should use a switch() case:
and i used enum to skip the this